# Weak Concurrent Stack for java

Tags: java, collections

What are the options for a [wait-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) stack with weak or soft references in java?

So far I've come up with:

```
ConcurrentLinkedDeque<SoftReference<T>> deque;

void push(T value) {
    deque.push(new SoftReference<T>(value));
}

T tryPop() {
    while (true) {
        SoftReference<T> ref = deque.pollLast();
        if (ref == null) {
            return null;
        }
        T value = ref.get();
        if (value != null) {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

With the problem that this leaves uncollected references in the deque,
and implementing collection won't be optimal since it requires traversing the deque.

Comment: Traversing the queue is unlikely to be a significant portion of the work compared to say a GC pause to clean them up or even creating the SoftReferences for that matter.

Comment: good point. However that depends on the deque size. I'd guess it begins to matter when it gets bigger than a few tens of thousands. Not my case here, though.